# Excel: Return value if cell contains a certain text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

there are 2 cells.

One contains string

"AA BB CC DD"

And the second one

"AABBCCCDD"

I want to make formula that return value "true", when cells contains "BB". If I use find or search formulas, it returns true for all of them. Nevertheless, there's another condition. I want to use this:

=IF(IS.NUMBER(SEARCH(" BB ".....

Search is consisted of 2 main parameter -> what and where. I want to add 2 values into "what". Something like:

If cell contains " BB " or "BeBe" then...

I hope it' clear.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `AND():` `=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...)))`?

Comment: I was going to suggest `=IF(OR(SEARCH("bb",A1),SEARCH("bebe",A1)),"Yes","No")`, but it gives a `#Value` error when either `bb` or `bebe` isn't found. So you could account for that, and use `IfError()` perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" BB ","BeBe"},A1))))>0
```

SEARCH() is not case sensitive so it will return true for "BEBE" If you want case sensitive use FIND:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISNUMBER(FIND({" BB ","BeBe"},A1))))>0
```

[image]

Comment: How come this formula doesn't throw errors when one of the conditions isn't found? In my comment above, using `Or()` with two searches will return `#VALUE` if one isn't found.

Comment: @the ISNUMBER() does that, if it throws an error it is not a number and therefore is FALSE which when multiplied by 1 returns 0.

Comment: @MartinJanáč If it were me, I would use the other answer, it is less typing and works just as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for multiple strings by passing array of strings `{}` and wrapping in `AND()`:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"AA","BB"},A1)))
```

Alternatively, you can wrap it in `OR()` if you need at least one match, not all of them:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"AA","BB"},A1)))
```

Comment: This is better than mine, less typing.  I would go with this.  Good job.

Comment: I was unaware that it would iterate the array properly, and I tried the AND first on my data and got what I thought I should, then I looked further and realized you are 100% correct, and therefore I learned something.  Wish I could give more than 1 upvote, just for making me learn something.